# Grant access to a certain IP using PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-403

Im working on a site which block range of IP's using htaccess and display a custom page saying "access denied" and a form asking for a security code for them to access it..

so if a certain IP in on the list and visit our site it will display the custom page.

then if he contact us we will provide the code for him to access the site.

My problem is I dont know how to edit the htaccess using php..or to let that IP access the site.

Thanks, hope you understand me.

**sample page** 
http://cjrtec.com/access-denied.php

Comment: I mean ... it's a combination of two problems 1. how to edit a file (which is somewhat simple and can be found in php-doc), 2. how is htaccess structured/formatted/configured/whatever, which is also simple, because there is docs for that too. so my advice is, do the work and rtfm.

Comment: ah.. ok thank you sir

Comment: Blocking by IP address is mostly useless, as IP addresses can be changed and/or spoofed. Also, many people may share the same IP address. Unless that's just what the boss wants, maybe you can come up with a better idea on how to restrict access to your application.

Comment: It's an extremely bad idea to control access based on IP address. Why not just use a login+password approach, especially if you are already providing a code to grant access? Moreover, htaccess is probably the *worst* place to arrange this. It's extremely inflexible, a pain in the ass to manage, non-flexible, one typo can cause your whole site to go down, it's less portable, et cetera. Just *don't* use htaccess for it. This can be arranged much easier in 3 lines of PHP.

Comment: If ip blocking is the only security, it would be a bad idea. I hope both ip blocking and access token / user-password / something else is being done.

Comment: thanks guys, I really appreciate your help.. actually the purpose of blocking the ips is because we don't want competitors to gather data from us...we blocked ips from   other countries